# How to show the id of the button when hover over it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Using the following code I can change the name of the button when user hovers over it. Is there a way to change the button's name with its id when user hovers over it (using JavaScript)?

```css
.button:hover span {
  display: none
}

.button:hover:before {
  content: "New name";
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<button class="button" id="some_id">
  <span>old name</span>
</button>
```

Comment: write `js`- eventlistener for `hover`

Comment: Like Rory said, you will need to use js, also add a listener for the hover event.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question to make the question clear that I'm looking for a JS solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `attr(id)`. See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) for further information.

```css
.button:hover span {
  display: none
}

.button:hover:before {
  content: attr(id);
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<button class="button" id="some_id">
  <span>old name</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one that changes things back...

```
onmouseover="this.innerHTML=this.id;"

onmouseout="this.id=this.innerHTML; this.innerHTML='old name';"
```

Just add these events to the button.

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy actually...

onmouseover="this.innerHTML=this.id;"

Just add this event to the button.

Comment: And what happens when you mouseout?